# If $h$ is closer to $f$ than to $g$, its integral on $\{f > g\}$ must "agree" with $f$'s?

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals

I have the following question (a result I would like to prove, with an admirable record of failing at it so far) -- I actually do not know if it is obvious or just plain wrong.

Let $f,g,h\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}_+$ be 3 (integrable) functions such that $\int_{[0,1]}f=\int_{[0,1]}g=\int_{[0,1]}h=1$; set $$A_{fg}\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\left\{x\in[0,1]\mid f(x) > g(x)\right\}$$
and write $\omega_f=\int_{A_{fg}} f$, $\omega_g=\int_{A_{fg}} g$, $\omega_h=\int_{A_{fg}} h$.

Suppose $\int_{[0,1]} \lvert g - h\rvert \geq \int_{[0,1]} \lvert f - h\rvert + \gamma$, for some constant $\gamma > 0$. Can we prove a quantitative bound on $\omega_h$, namely that it must be "closer to $\omega_f$ than to $\omega_g$?".

I hope that a statement of this form holds:

> There exists an absolute constant $c>0$ (e.g., $1/10$) such that $\omega_h > \frac{\omega_f+\omega_g}{2}+c\cdot\gamma$.

It does sound "intuitive" to me, yet I have learnt not to give too much credit to my intuition. Especially since I have been struggling with this for one day now, and quite a few sheets of paper: I know how to prove it with the extra assumption that $\int_{[0,1]} \lvert f - h\rvert \leq \frac{\gamma}{10}$, but this is not enough for my purpose.

*Small note:* one can assume without loss of generality $f,g,h$ to be "regular enough" (continuous, for instance).

Answer (score 3):

This will not work. For small $\delta>0$, let's define $f(x)=1$,
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & 0<x<1/2 \\ 1 & 1/2 < x < 1-\delta \\
\frac{1+2\delta}{2\delta} & 1-\delta<x< 1 \end{cases} , \quad
h(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1+\delta}{2\delta} & 1/2< x < 1/2 + \delta \\
1/2 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases} .
$$
Then $A=[0,1/2]$, so $\omega_h=(1/2)(\omega_f+\omega_g)$ (since $g=0$, $h=1/2$, $f=1$ on $A$), and I have a counterexample if I can verify that $\|g-h\|_1>\|f-h\|_1$.

This we can of course do by a straightforward explicit calculation. However, we can also (more conveniently) argue as follows: Observe that the bumps of $g$, $h$ have area $\approx 1/2$ (they have to, to make $\int f=\int g=1$). Now away from the bumps, that is, for most points in $[0,1]$, we have that $|f-h|=|g-h|=1/2$. We then observe that $\int |g-h|$ picks up two bumps, while only the bump of $h$ contributes to $\int |f-h|$. Thus $\int|f-h|\approx 1$, $\int |g-h|\approx 3/2$, and in particular, $\int|g-h|>\int |f-h|$, as desired.

Comment: Indeed -- thanks for the counterexample! I'll award you the bounty at the end of the period or close to it anyway, but out of curiosity and to see whether my intuition could be fixed*: what if instead of $A$, one considered the set $$B\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \{f\geq g\}$$ ? Would my wishful-but-wrong claim hold, in your opinion? (in your example, $B=[0,1-\delta]$).

* This is actually a kind of result that would come very handy for an approach I am trying.

Comment: I don't think this will fundamentally change anything. We could just slightly modify $f$ to be $1+\epsilon$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $1-\epsilon$ on $(1/2,1)$ and then still $B=[0,1/2]$ and all quantities of interest still have almost the same values.

Comment: Yes, that's also what I thought... damn (but thanks!).